# Why does itoa() modify the passed char[] instead of returning char[]?

Tags: c++, c

Is there any reason why the itoa() function returns void and stores the result in the char[] array passed to it, instead of returning char[] ?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to return a pointer to memory you allocate in a function.

Comment: Not wasting memory? After all, if you return char[] in C (for example, by allocating a new chunk of memory within your function), the caller would have to deallocate it.

Comment: In C++ you cannot return arrays from functions or pass arrays into functions. It's all done with pointers, which brings a whole different set of problems that would take far too long to explain in this comment.

Comment: @chris: please don't ever listen to anyone who says it's a bad idea, they don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: In fact the C++ reference says that it return the string: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: @RobinRobinovic, `itoa` isn't even a standard function.

Comment: @n.m., I personally prefer it this way when working with C functions. I actually do find it annoying when I have to manage memory that some function decides it wants to allocate and have me take care of. At least when I manage my own, I know exactly where it's allocated and can just use something that will manage it for me (C++) right off the bat.

Comment: @chris It's a pain if you cannot work out how big the buffer needs to be in advance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'll give you that, but hopefully there's at least another function to tell you.

Comment: @chris It can be inefficient when that function that gives you the buffer size has to do a whole bunch of work. And then when you call the function to fill out the buffer, that same work is repeated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Again a good point. In some cases, it is optimal to allocate it in the function, and in some others, there's not much reason to.

Comment: @chris It may or may not make sense to avoid allocations, depending on the kind of library you are writing. Some libraries naturally allocate memory and others don't. If your library allocates and exposes allocated memory to the user, it makes no sense whatsoever to avoid returning it from a function. Creating objects on free store is a task like any other task, and like any other task it's subject to abstraction into a function of its own.

Comment: @n.m., I was really thinking of just allocators when saying "generally" in my first comment. I completely agree there's no reason to forbid allocators.

Comment: There is no perfect solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that the function expects the caller to allocate and supply the buffer. This is very standard in C. If the function returned a new buffer, the caller would have to take care of deallocating it, and it would force the buffer to be dynamically allocated. By asking the caller to supply the buffer, the function allows the buffer to be allocated with automatic storage, or dynamically allocated.

And in fact, the versions of `itoa` that I am familiar with do indeed return the buffer that the caller provided, rather than return `void`.

Answer (score 3):

A C function cannot return an array.

There are several ways a C function can do the equivalent of returning an array; none of them are pretty.

1. The caller can pass a pointer to the first element of an array, along with an indication of how big the array is. The caller can then fill in the pointed-to array. This requires the caller to determine how much space is going to be needed.
2. The function can define a `static` array and return a pointer to its first element. This requires the size of the array to be fixed at compile time. It also means that successive calls will clobber the array.
3. The function can allocate an array using `malloc()`, and return a pointer to its first element. This is the most flexible approach, but the caller is then responsible for calling `free()` to deallocate the buffer, and must also be prepared to handle an allocation failure.

Apparently the designers of the `itoa()` function chose option 1, which in this case was probably the least bad alternative.

Furthermore, there is no `itoa()` function defined either by the ISO C standard or by POSIX. Apparently *some* C runtime libraries define it as an extension, but on several systems I've tried (Solaris and a few flavors of Linux) it doesn't exist. If you care about portability, I suggest finding a different way to convert integers to strings, probably `sprintf` or `snprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), `itoa` returns the second input parameter, not `void`. Functions that don't need to modify the input string would expect a `const char *` according to C standards. Note though that `itoa` is not part of ANSI-C (although I don't know a single compiler that does not support it).

Comment: I don't know of a single compiler that *does* support it. I can believe that some C runtime *libraries* do support it -- but it doesn't exist on any of the systems I have access to at the moment (Solaris and several flavors of Linux).

Comment: @KeithThompson: MSVC is about the only system that comes to mind that has pretty much always supported `itoa (...)`. It's neither ANSI C nor POSIX, so only oddballs like Microsoft will implement it generally :)